# Run tmux always when I open terminal

Tags: shell, tmux, terminal-emulator

I usually open *lxterminal* with bash shell where I usually type *tmux* command first.

I'd like to have launched tmux command automatically, so I tried to add this command to `~/.bash_profile` or to `~/.profile` files but none of them launched the tmux automatically.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Launch `lxterm -e tmux` instead?

Comment: It's `lxterminal`. When I run `lxterminal -e tmux`, alias in `~/.bash_aliases` for `tmux` is not applied and it has no advantage, I still would have to type `tmux` instead of being launched automatically after `bash`.

Comment: sorry i assumed lxterm equals lxterminal. The normal solution is to change this in your window manager and automatically launch it when you start a terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not recommended to do what you wanted , usually I place something similar for ttyX  , edit yor bashrc , add the following lines , which will allow any `XTERM` based terminal to launch tmux on start.

`[[ $TERM = "xterm" ]] && { tmux && exit 0; }`

You should add a new shortcut or launch terminal with custom shell , which is tmux. ( not sure if lxterm support this )

Comment: This starts tmux whenever you run bash in an X terminal. That's very invasive: it means you can never run an interactive shell in an X terminal outside tmux.

Answer (score 5):

Change your menu entries, keybindings, shell aliases, or whatever you use to run Lxterminal to run `lxterminal --command tmux`.

Adding `tmux` to `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` is no good: these files are read only when you log in. Adding `tmux` to `~/.bashrc` is no good either: that would start `tmux` in any instance of bash, not just the ones started by lxterminal.

Comment: I usually start `lxterminal` via `dmenu` launcher, I'm not sure if it supports some aliases.